# Recursively delete folders where folder name contains a number

Tags: arrays, powershell

Good afternoon all,

I am attempting to delete folders at a specific location containing a number in the name, which can be any number in the array.

```
$fso = New-Object -com "Scripting.FileSystemObject"
$Versionarray = (13..20)
$folder = 
$fso.GetFolder("$env:USERPROFILE\appdata\local\Microsoft\OneDrive")

    foreach ($subfolder in $folder.SubFolders)
    {
    If ($subfolder.Name -match "$Versionarray")
    {
        remove-item $subfolder.Path -Verbose
    }    
}
```

Please see an example of the following folders it will sift through below:

- 18.172.0826.0010
- 18.172.0826.0010_2
- 18.172.0826.0015
- 18.172.0920.0015
- 18.172.0920.0015_1
- logs
- settings
- setup

If I change the "VersionArray"array to the variable "18" instead, it will start to remove the folders. It doesn't appear to be going through each number of the array. I need it to be an array to future-proof the script as the number represents a version of OneDrive.

Thank you for looking over this.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you use the `FileSystemObject` instead of `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: @Tomalak No reason to be honest, just grasping at straws at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from your initial idea to have a list of items that must be contained in the subfolder name, we can do a pipeline like this:

```
$Versionarray = 13..20

Get-ChildItem "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\OneDrive" -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $item = $_
    $item -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] -and (
        $Versionarray | Where-Object { $item.Name.Contains($_) }
    )
} | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

Notes:

- `Get-ChildItem` returns all subfolders and files in a folder. Drop `-Recurse` if you don't need that.
- `Where-Object` filters any list of objects according to a condition. Any result other than 0, $false, $null, or the empty string/empty list will be considered $true. It's not necessary to actually return `$true`, as long as anything is returned at all.
- `$_` is the "current item" in the pipeline
- `$foo -is [Fully.Qualified.ClassName]` checks if an object is of a certain class. In this case, we only want to look at [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo` objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) and ignore all files.
- `$Versionarray | Where-Object { $item.Name.Contains($_) }` filters the $Versionarray down to those elements that are contained in the folder name. You could use `.StartsWith()` or any other method of [.NET strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.7.2) in its place.
- Any object that "survives" the `Where-Object` filter is passed to `Remove-Item`
- `-WhatIf` performs a dry-run, drop it when you're sure the right thing will happen.

Comment: No words, probably really basic for you but this was driving me mad. Brilliant explanation as well. Thank you kindly!

Comment: Off the top of your head. Is there anyway to force the deletion of these folders? At the moment it's asking for whether I want to continue "[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):" it's also not removing some of the folders as they are not empty.

Comment: Yes. `Remove-Item` supports a `-Force` argument.